# How to download multiple accession from UniProt using R?

Tags: r, fasta, bioconductor

I have a huge list of `UniProt` accession numbers and I need to retrieve the FASTA sequences from `UniProt` website. Is there any R script for doing that? I know I can do it from UniProt website but this will be used for further developing a script for downstream mass spec analysis.

I am using the following script but it says

> Error in getFASTAFromUniProt(c("P62754", "Q8K094", "Q64337")) : could
>   not find function "getFASTAFromUniProt"

```
if (!requireNamespace("BiocManager", quietly = TRUE))
install.packages("BiocManager")

BiocManager::install("Rcpi")

library( Rcpi ) 
fastas <- getFASTAFromUniProt( c( "P62754", "Q8K094", "Q64337" ) ) 
write("_uniprot_downloads", "uniprot.fasta" )
```

Comment: Hey, do you have problems with rJava, an error like this? onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava'

Comment: @StupidWolf  yes ...it goes like this:                                                                                                    
                                                                                                                            > library( Rcpi )
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘Rcpi’:
 .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:
  call: fun(libname, pkgname)
  error: No CurrentVersion entry in Software/JavaSoft registry! Try re-installing Java and make sure R and Java have matching architectures.

Comment: @ StupidWolf I reinstalled the Java, but still same problem.

Comment: it's a bit tricky. What worked for me was exit R, do R CMD javareconf on terminal and then restart R